# I got the error "KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25760/3076371497.py in <module>"

Tags: python, keyerror, traceback

I wrote the following code in Jupyter Notebook with the aim of collecting some information from Google Maps.

```
import datetime
import googlemaps
import csv
import pandas
import time
from datetime import datetime

file = open('key.txt', 'r')
key = file.read().strip()

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=key)

x=time.localtime()

while 1:
        ## consultation BR-040 urban (1) - BSB - BH
        query_040urb1AB = gmaps.distance_matrix('-19.741224, -44.148914', '-19.813856, -44.092239', mode='driving', departure_time='now')
        a = str(datetime.now())
        b = query_040urb1AB['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration_in_traffic']['value']

        consulta_final_040urb1AB = {'Segment': '1', 'Direction': 'BSB-BH', 'Data': str(datetime.now()),
                          'Origin': query_040urb1AB['origin_addresses'], 'Destination': query_040urb1AB['destination_addresses'], 'Travel Time': query_040urb1AB['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration_in_traffic'] ['value']}

        print(query_final_040urb1AB)
        with open('040urb1AB.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as csvfile:
            csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',').writerow([a,b])

        ## consultation BR-040 urban (1) - BH - BSB
        query_040urb1BA = gmaps.distance_matrix('-19.813770, -44.092143', '-19.741235, -44.148780', mode='driving', departure_time='now')
        a = str(datetime.now())
        b = query_040urb1BA['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration_in_traffic']['value']

        consulta_final_040urb1BA = {'Segment': '1', 'Direction': 'BH-BSB', 'Data': str(datetime.now()),
                          'Origin': query_040urb1BA['origin_addresses'], 'Destination': query_040urb1BA['destination_addresses'], 'Travel Time': query_040urb1BA['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration_in_traffic'] ['value']}

        print(query_final_040urb1BA)
        with open('040urb1BA.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as csvfile:
            csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',').writerow([a,b])
```

Entering the coordinates of the start and end location of the collection, the code should return: date and time of collection, vehicle origin, vehicle destination and travel time. This should happen uninterruptedly. However, after running for a while, the code always ends with the following error message:

```
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25760/3076371497.py in <module>
    113 query_262urb1AB = gmaps.distance_matrix('-19.977448, -44.255544', '-19.961123, -44.336237', mode='driving', departure_time='now')
    114 a = str(datetime.now())
--> 115 b = query_262urb1AB['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration_in_traffic']['value']
    116
    117 final_query_262urb1AB = {'Segment': '1', 'Direction': 'BH-UBE', 'Data': str(datetime.now()),

KeyError: 'duration_in_traffic'
```

How can I understand the reason of this error and how to fix it and make the code not stop running?

Comment: Have you printed out the intermediate values?  The error is very clear -- what ever is in row 0 element 0 does not contain a key called `duration_in_traffic`.